# Registering an Application to a URL Protocol: immediate termination

Tags: c#, windows, url, registry

Registered my program according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx.

The association seems to be working, because if I enter my custom url in a browser, it asks for permission to use my program. however, whenever the program is started through url, it terminates, producing the standard "send microsoft an error report" dialog. When I start it from the command line, using the exact same arguments (quadruple-checked of course) as chrome and ie are passing, it works perfectly fine.

The error signature is as follows (hand copied, the text field in the error reporting window doesn't let you copy -.-')

```
EventType: clr20r3 P1: docreg2.exe P2: 1.0.0.0 P3: 4e16fb9b
P4: mscorlib P5 2.0.0.0 P6 4d8c190a P7: 344a P8: d8
P9: system.io.filenotfoundexception
```

I wonder what's going on...

Comment: Standard debugging practices will help you here. Either sensible error handling, or message boxes to track down the point it crashes. Having said that, I expect it is the working path as Daniel said and your app making invalid assumptions.

Comment: Oh, and you can copy from the event log where it's also reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the starting directory of the program in each case.

Comment: It starts in a subdirectory of the browser whenever it's called from there. Shouldn't make a difference though?

Comment: It can't find a file.  Obviously you are trying to access some file or have some dependency that have relative path to it.

Comment: Loading one settings file using relative path, wich i thought was nested in a try...catch. Needless to say; it wasn't. *facepalm*